# Valve and pump symbol using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I'm wondering if there is a library for the pump and the valve symbol. 
I want to draw the following schematics using TikZ.

[image: Pump station]

using something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{VALVEPUMPPACAKGE}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0)  to[pump] (2,0) -- (4,0) to[valve] (4,-2);

   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, but one could easily construct one.  I have tutorials (for Circuitikz) at http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm

Comment: to[pump] would be difficult.  Normally components connect in straight lines through the center.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JohnKormylo. I'll have a look at the tutorial. I figgure I'll just draw the pump, and (try to) make symbols for the valves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to draw it line by line.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\valve}[3]{%
    \draw (#1-.5,#2) -- (#1+.5,#2) -- (#1-.5,#2-2) -- (#1+.5,#2-2) -- cycle;
    \draw (#1,#2-1) -- (#1-.5,#2-1);
    \draw (#1-.5,#2-1.45) rectangle (#1-1.25,#2-.65);
    \node at (#1-2.5,#2-1) {\bf #3};
}

\newcommand{\process}[3]{%
    \draw [rounded corners=1.5mm] (#1-.5,#2) rectangle (#1+.5,#2-2);
    \node at (#1-2,#2-1) {\bf #3};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[ultra thick]

        %% pump
        \draw (0,-.2) --  (2,-.2) -- (1,.8) -- (0,-.2);
        \filldraw [color=white,draw=black](1,1) circle (1cm);
        \draw [->] (-2,1) -- (1,1);
        \draw [->] (1,2) -- (2,2);
        \node at (1,-.75) {\bf Pump};

        \draw (2,2) -- (6,2);
        \draw (6,2) -- (6,-2);

        % <- valve 1

        \draw (6,-4) -- (6,-6);

        % <- process 1

        \draw (6,-8) -- (6,-10) -- (-2,-10);
        \draw (6,2) -- (12,2) -- (12,-2);

        % <- valve 2

        \draw (12,-4) -- (12,-6);

        % <- process 2

        \draw (12,-8) -- (12,-10) -- (6,-10);

    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[thick]

        \valve{6}{-2}{Valve 1}
        \process{6}{-6}{Process 1}
        \valve{12}{-2}{Valve2}
        \process{12}{-6}{Process 2}

    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Pump station]

Comment: It is normally preferred to post a complete document including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages, so that one can simply cut and paste and try out the solution.

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that.

Comment: Looks great. Might want to add `border=2pt` option to the `\documentclass`.  For future improvement I would recommend you define macros for things which are repetitive. For example, you could define macros for `\Valve` and specify the coordinate for the location of the `\Valve` as parameters. And if you want to go farther, define you own custom shapes with appropriate anchors.

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks for the replies.
I took your advice and improved the source. 
It seems that defining shapes is a bit heavy at the moment.

Comment: @DavidKristiansen Did you ever make any macros? If so, you might be interested in http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=90728#p90728

Comment: @Johannes_B: I wish I saw this a year ago! Thanks, I will bookmark it incase I ever will need those symbols again.